# Filter images from array of Dictionary using predicate iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of dictionary, can you tell me how I can filter these images based on dictionary keys?

```
{ test1 = "<UIImage: 0x6000002a10e0> size {1668, 2500} orientation 0 scale 1.000000"; },
{ test2 = "<UIImage: 0x6040002a0e40> size {4288, 2848} orientation 0 scale 1.000000"; }
```

Comment: Filter according to what exactly? What's the reason why you should keep or remove one of the dictionary?

Comment: according to key.

Comment: `NSArray *filtered = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings){ return (evaluatedObject[@"test1"] == nil); }];`?

Comment: i used that but i'm getting array of dictionary :(  , i want only images

Comment: Your question is unclear. What you want is an array of images? Because that what suggest your last comment, but not your question. Please be clear, edit your question with desired output.

Comment: thanks :)  my problem solved  and sorry i couldn't clear that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted something like this?

```
NSArray *imageDicts = @[@{@"test1": [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat"]}, @{@"test2": [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat"]}, @{@"test3": @"string, should be ignored"}];
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *info in imageDicts) {
    for (NSString *key in [info allKeys]) {
        id obj = info[key];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
            [images addObject:obj];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", images);
```

Output:

```
TestProject[15709:21109977] (
    "<UIImage: 0x60c0000a5460>, {1200, 1199}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60c0000a5760>, {1200, 1199}"
)
```